# How to extend the lifetime of a local variable at the end of an if/else statement?

Tags: c++

I'm making a really simple program (I'm a total newbie) that asks the user to input either **1** for **multiplication** or **2** for **division**, then asks them to input **2 numbers** to then be calculated and then the result will be printed.

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "1 for Multiplication, 2 for Division\n";
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;

    if (x == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter 1st Number\n";
        int y;
        std::cin >> y;

        std::cout << "Enter 2nd Number\n";
        int z;

        std::cin >> z;

        int c{ z * y };
        std::cout << c;
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "Enter 1st Number\n";
        int y;
        std::cin >> y;

        std::cout << "Enter 2nd Number\n";
        int z;
        std::cin >> z;

        int c{ y / z };
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

My question is, `c` here is a local variable, and is "destroyed" at the end of the `if/else` statement. What should I do to extend the lifetime of the variable `c`, in case I want to continue to use the result and do another calculation with it?

Comment: In this case I would define `c` ahead of the `if` so that it exists in a wider scope. The other options require dynamic scope, and that can be a <expletive deleted> to manage.

Comment: Actually, I missed a decent non-dynamic option: [Use a function!](https://godbolt.org/z/76Wos8hvf)

Comment: You can also half the amount of code, the only line that is actually different in your if/else is `int c{ z * y };` and `int c{ y / z };` The rest of the code only needs to be done once outside the `if`

Comment: Which segs nicely to my next suggestion: [Use a smarter function](https://godbolt.org/z/j8f48n95q)!

Comment: Why functions? Separation of Responsibilities! The less you try to do all at once, the easier the code is to prove correct. If you can write a "get user input" function, that function is simple and you can test it by itself.  Then use it with confidence in more complicated functions comprised of other little-and-simple functions, all tested individually and known to work. If you write code in little block and then assemble the blocks like you would Lego to write more complicated programs, you'll find there's no such thing as a big problem, just combinations of little problems.

Comment: Example: https://godbolt.org/z/dMbeEehjM

Comment: Side note: Enter 3 as the choice and you'll see a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Simply move `c` outside of the `if/else` so it exists in a higher scope, eg:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "1 for Multiplication, 2 for Division\n";
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;

    int c;

    if (x == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter 1st Number\n";
        int y;
        std::cin >> y;

        std::cout << "Enter 2nd Number\n";
        int z;
        std::cin >> z;

        c = z * y;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Enter 1st Number\n";
        int y;
        std::cin >> y;

        std::cout << "Enter 2nd Number\n";
        int z;
        std::cin >> z;

        c = y / z;
    }

    std::cout << c;
}
```

And since your `if/else` is basically just repeating code, you can (and should) move the repeated variables/operations into the higher scope, too:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "1 for Multiplication, 2 for Division\n";
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << "Enter 1st Number\n";
    int y;
    std::cin >> y;

    std::cout << "Enter 2nd Number\n";
    int z;
    std::cin >> z;

    int c;
    if (x == 1)
        c = z * y;
    else
        c = y / z;

    std::cout << c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    // choice of operation
    //----------------------
    
    std::cout << "1 for Multiplication, 2 for Division\n";
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    
    //always test if we have a valid input
    //we shouldn't continue if the value of x is not valid
    if (!((x == 1) || (x == 2))) {
        std::cerr << "No valid input\n";
        return -1; // no reason to continue
    }

    // operands
    //----------
    
    std::cout << "Enter 1st Number\n";
    int y;
    std::cin >> y;

    std::cout << "Enter 2nd Number\n";
    int z;
    std::cin >> z;

    // result
    //--------

    int c
    {
        (x == 1) // x either 1 or 2
        ? y * z  // case 1: mult
        : y / z  // else  : div
    };

    // since we have only two options,
    // the use of the ternary operator deemed to be
    // the simplest choice, which is basically the same as:
    // if (x == 1) { c=y*x; } else { c=y/x; }
    // see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator
    
    /* for more options
    int c;
    switch (x) {
        case 1: c = y * z; break; // mult
        case 2: c = y / z; break; // div
        case 3: c = y + z; break; // add
        ...
        default: whatever the default action/result should be
    } */
    
    std::cout << c;
}
```

Comment: @Erdal Küçük: better still, as user4581301 suggested, the code should probably  be refactored into functions: a) get_value() of x, y, z, then b) compute(), to calculate c

Comment: @paulsm4 I agree, that's why i structured the code in a particular way (comment headers), but since user4581301 already mentioned the usage of functions and the OP noted that he/she is a beginner, i wanted to stay as close as possible to the original code and didn't want to introduce more complexity (although the use of the conditional operator was a bad choice therein).

Comment: @user4581301 I don't know why but yeah, all professors complain about it...

Comment: I like this answer. All it needed was some explanation, and not that it's got it, rock and rule. It gives the asker a way to get what they want with the least possible disturbance. I did all of my disturbing in comments because it was sidebar material.